# Is my_require_once needed?

Tags: php

Is it a good idea to use some 'my_require_once' function instead of standard require_once to check if the required file exists and handle the case if not (for example, display some special error page instead of FATAL_Error message displaying the structure of your application (path, filenames etc.) or is it just useless? If second, then, what is a better practice to include files?

**Update:**

I dont want to disable all error messages, though, while I'm not very experienced in PHP and I'm afraid it can hide some bugs from me for quite a long time.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want end users to see raw error messages, configure an error page in your webserver.

Comment: the require should only ever fail under 'exceptional' circumstances, if you feel the need to trap the errors separately, then perhaps it s failing to often

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the difference between the `require_once()` and `include_once()` functions is that the `require_once()` causes PHP to deliver a fatal error and script execution stops.  So if you want to keep executing then use `include_once()` and simply use it in an `if` statement to see if your file was included and then handle the errors as necessary.

**EDIT**

If you would like to suppress an error message in PHP you can use the `@` symbol.

```
if(!@include_once("somefile.txt")) {
    print("File could not be found...");
}
```